# Error when compare value in array using javascript?

Tags: javascript

I have a sample code:

```
var find = ['iphone 3', 'iphone 4', 'iphone 5'];
var search = 'iphone 5';
for(i=0; i<find.length; i++) {
   if(search == find[i]) {
      alert('Yes');
   } else {
      alert('No');
   }
}
```

When I run code, result 2 alert(`alert('Yes') and alert('No')`), but result exactly is only a `alert('Yes'),` how to fix it ?

Comment: This seems to be working completely fine. Two `No`s followed by one `Yes`.

Comment: @YogendraSingh: I think the OP doesn't want the _"no"_'s to show

Comment: @EliasVanOotegem: I answered that part with an `if`.

Comment: @YogendraSingh: So I see, it's pretty much exactly the same as I answered. Also: no need for the `present` var in your anser, just `if (i < find.length)` will work: you're using a break statement, if that break is never encountered, i === find.length, else, it'll always be smaller. nitpicking, I know, but I like to use as little vars as possible

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, you don't want `no` to be alerted when there is no match found:

```
var find = ['iphone 3', 'iphone 4', 'iphone 5'];
var search = 'iphone 5';
for(i=0; i<find.length; i++)
{
    if(search == find[i])
    {
       alert('Yes');
       break;//stop loop, found match
    }
}
```

Just don't provide the `else` branch. Oh, and if you don't care about older browsers:

```
if (find.indexOf(search) !== -1)
{
    alert('yes');
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This can be done simply with `.indexOf`:

```
if ( find.indexOf( search ) > -1 ) {

    alert('Yes');

} else {

    alert('No');

}
```

Replace this with the entirety of your code *excluding* the variable declarations.

Answer (score 0):

**If you want to alert the match found** then use a flag to mark where match was found or no. In the end, use the flag to alert the respective message as below:

```
 var find = ['iphone 3', 'iphone 4', 'iphone 5'];
 var search = 'iphone 5';
 var present = false;
 for(i=0; i<find.length; i++) {
     if(search == find[i]) {
       present = true;
       break;
     }
 }
 if(present) {
  alert('Yes');
 } else {
  alert('No');
 }
```

Please Note: There could be better ways but trying the help following your algorithm only.